# Project Euler #7 - 10001st prime

Tags: programming-challenge, primes, swift

I just finished [Project Euler #7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7) in Swift, and since there is not any version yet on Code Review, I would like to have some comments on what I did to try to improve it.

> By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
>
> What is the 10 001st prime number?

```
import Foundation

func isPrime(number:Int) -> Bool {
    
    if number == 1 {
        return false
    }
    else if number < 4 {
        return true
    }
    else if number % 2 == 0 {
        return false
    }
    else if number < 9 {
        return true
    }
    else if number % 3 == 0 {
        return false
    }
    else {
        let maxPrime = Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(number))))
        
        for var i = 5; i <= maxPrime; i += 6 {
            if number % i == 0  || number % (i + 2) == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    
    return true
}

func getNumberForXthPrime(prime:Int) -> Int {
    
    var xThPrime = prime - 1 // We skip the prime 2 with the += 2
    var number = 1
    
    while xThPrime > 0 {
        
        number += 2
        if isPrime(number) {
            xThPrime--
        }
    }
    
    return number
}

func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(operation:(xThPrime:Int) -> Int) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let number = operation(xThPrime: 10_001)
    println(number)
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    println("Time elapsed : \(timeElapsed) s")
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(getNumberForXthPrime)
```

The code executes in 0.0181439518928528 s.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I added the Euler problem description and a link to the problem for you. I hope you get some good reviews!

Comment: Is the goal here performance or readability?

Comment: Performance and/or readability. Anything you want to point out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
func isPrime(number:Int) -> Bool { ... }
```

The test `if number < 9` is not needed because that is covered by the general
`else` case, and I think that `number <= 3` is easier to understand than `if number < 4`.

A more general question is how the function should deal with zero or 
negative arguments. The term "prime number" is only defined for *positive* integers,
and the `number` argument is certainly positive in *this* program. But you might
reuse the same function for other Project Euler challenges as a kind of library
function and then it makes sense check for a valid argument.
There are two possible methods:

```
assert(number > 0, "argument must be positive")
precondition(number > 0, "argument must be positive")
```

The difference is that (by default) `assert()` is only checked in the Debug build,
but not in Release build.
`precondition()` is checked always unless you set the optimization level
to `-Ofast`.

You might also consider to change the argument type from `Int` to `UInt`.

---

```
func getNumberForXthPrime(prime:Int) -> Int { ... }
```

The function name is not well chosen. In Objective-C, the "get" prefix is used
only for functions that return a value indirectly (compare
["Coding Guidelines for Cocoa"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)) and I think this convention applies to Swift
programs as well. Also the function does not return a "number" but a "prime",
and the argument `prime: Int` is not a prime. I would change that simply to

```
func nthPrime(n : Int) -> Int { ... }
```

When called with `n = 1`, it returns `1` and not `2`. Again, this is not relevant
in this particular program, but you should fix it if you want to reuse the
function for other challenges.

Instead of a local counting variable

```
var xThPrime = prime - 1
```

you can also modify the local parameter variable by declaring it with `var`,
but that is up to you to decide if you find it more readable or not.
The function would then look like this:

```
func nthPrime(var n : Int) -> Int {

    assert(n > 0, "argument must be positive")

    if n == 1 {
        return 2
    }

    var number = 3
    n -= 2 // 3 is the second prime

    while n > 0 {
        number += 2
        if isPrime(number) {
            n--
        }
    }

    return number
}
```

---

```
func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(operation:(xThPrime:Int) -> Int) { ... }
```

I already made a suggestion in my answer to your other question 
[Project Euler #8 - Largest product in a series](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74778/project-euler-8-largest-product-in-a-series) to change the timing function for better code reuse.
Applied to this problem, it would look like

```
func euler7() {
    let result = nthPrime(10_001)
    println(result)
}

func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(operation:()->Void) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    println("Time elapsed : \(timeElapsed) s")
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(euler7)
```

---

Finally, some possible **performance** improvements. Your program is fast enough for the Project Euler Problem. It might be too slow to find larger prime
numbers. On my computer, your method takes

- 0.01 s to find the 10 001st prime number, and
- 10.4 s to find the 1 000 000st prime number.

A simple improvement would be to *remember* the primes that were already
found and pass that as an array to the `isPrime()` function which then
would only try to divide by *prime numbers*:

```
func isPrime(number:Int, primes: [Int]) -> Bool {

    let maxPrime = Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(number))))
    for prime in primes {
        if prime > maxPrime {
            break
        }
        if number % prime == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func nthPrime(var n : Int) -> Int {

    var primes = [2, 3]

    if n <= primes.count {
        return primes[n-1]
    }

    var number = primes.last!
    n -= primes.count

    while n > 0 {
        number += 2
        if isPrime(number, primes) {
            primes.append(number)
            n--
        }
    }

    return number
}
```

Now we have

- 0.01 s to find the 10 001st prime number, and
- 6 s to find the 1 000 000st prime number.

The ["Sieve of Eratosthenes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a very fast method
to find a large number of primes. However, it requires more memory, and you
have to estimate in advance how large the searched prime will be.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
func nthPrime(var n : Int) -> Int {

    assert(n > 0, "argument must be positive")

    // The below estimate is only valid for n > 6:
    if n <= 6 {
        return [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13][n-1]
    }

    // Upper bound from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number:
    let d = Double(n)
    let upperBound = Int(d * (log(d) + log(log(d))))

    var composite = [Bool](count: upperBound + 1, repeatedValue: false)
    var x = 2
    let maxPrime = Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(upperBound))))

    while x <= maxPrime {
        if !composite[x] {
            if (--n == 0) {
                return x
            }
            for var y = x*x; y <= upperBound; y += x {
                composite[y] = true
            }
        }
        x++
    }
    while x <= upperBound {
        if !composite[x] {
            if (--n == 0) {
                return x
            }
        }
        x++
    }

    assertionFailure("Fatal error")
    return -1
}
```

This is considerably faster:

- 0.001 s to find the 10 001st prime number, and
- 0.17 s to find the 1 000 000st prime number.

Comment: Really nice review! I Learned a lot.
Just to complete it, you should add `assert(n > 0, "argument must be positive")` in the nthPrime using the sieve. Or a precondition.

Comment: @Mehdi.Sqalli: You are welcome! – Done. – Waiting for PE #10 :)

Answer (score 5):

```
for var i = 5; i <= maxPrime; i += 6 {
    if number % i == 0  || number % (i + 2) == 0 {
        return false
    }
}
```

We can implement some Swift syntax here:

```
for i in stride(from:5 through:maxPrime by: 6) {
    if number % i == 0 || number % (i + 2) == 0 {
        return false
    }
}
```

I don't know how this would compare in terms of performance however.  I suspect it's the same or better however.

Comment: It is kind of weird. It's actually 10 times slower.

It goes from 0.018s to 0.18s, which is odd...

Anyone knows why ?

Comment: @Mehdi.Sqalli: In my test, `stride()` is *much* slower in Debug mode (0.17 vs 0.02 seconds), but only *slightly* slower in Release mode (0.01 vs 0.009 s).

Comment: Yep I was in Debug mode. It is slightly slower in Release mode though...