# Project Euler #8 - Largest product in a series

Tags: programming-challenge, swift

I just finished [Project Euler #8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) in Swift, and since there is not any version yet on Code Review, I would like to have some comments on what I did to try to improve it.

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
> greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
> 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
> 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
> 12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
> 66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
> 62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
> 30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
> 70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
> 65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
> 52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
> 53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
> 83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
> 82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
> 16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
> 17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
> 24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
> 07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
> 84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
> 05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
> 71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest
> product. What is the value of this product?

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        get {
            let subStart = advance(self.startIndex, r.startIndex, self.endIndex)
            let subEnd = advance(subStart, r.endIndex - r.startIndex, self.endIndex)
            return self.substringWithRange(Range(start: subStart, end: subEnd))
        }
    }
    func substring(from: Int, length: Int) -> String {
        let end = from + length
        return self[from..<end]
    }
}

func largestProduct(digits:Int) -> Int {
    
    let str = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
    
    var maxNumber = 0
    let maxLength = countElements(str) - digits
    for var i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i {
        
        let strNumber = str.substring(i, length: digits)
        
        var number = 1
        for char in strNumber {
            let charNumber = String(char).toInt()!
            number *= charNumber
        }
        
        if number > maxNumber {
            maxNumber = number
        }
    }
    
    return maxNumber
}

func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(operation:(Int) -> Int) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let number = operation(4)
    println(number)
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    println("Time elapsed : \(timeElapsed) s")
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(largestProduct)
```

The code executes in 0.0799770355224609 s

Comment: I have taken the liberty to undo your last edit. Compare "[What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)", in particular *"You must not edit the code in the question, ..."* and *"You also should not append your revised code to the question. ..."*

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks, I did not know that. So how someone is supposed to try and make the code better/cleaner/faster in the future while comparing to the latest version ?
Posting a new question seems overkill to me...

Comment: The above referenced meta answer lists all your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not know swift, but here's a java code to fasten the calculation. Please find the algorithm inline with the comments.:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String input ="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    int digit = 13;
    // 1.calculate the initial product of first 13 numbers.
    long max = getProduct(input,0,digit); 

    long prevVal = max;
    // Run a loop and use sliding window concept.
    // i.e remove the first number of the window from the product and add the new one.
    // For window size 3, with input "10345", prevVal = 1*0*3 for window "103". 
    // Slide the window to prevVal  = (1*0*3)/1 * 3; for window "034".
    // In case if removed element is 0, recalculate the window product.
    // For window "345", do prevVal = 3*4*5 instead of the above rule.
    for(int i=digit;i<input.length();i++){
        int leftVal = input.charAt(i-digit)-48;
        if(leftVal!=0){
            if(prevVal!=0){ // An optimisation to avert calculation if prevVal is 0
            // Sliding the window.
            prevVal = (prevVal/leftVal) * (input.charAt(i)-48);
            }
        }else{
            // Recalculation because of 0.
            prevVal = getProduct(input,i-digit+1,i+1);;
        }
        max = Math.max(max,prevVal);
    }
    System.out.println(">> " + max);
}

// calculates the product for the given window size , i.e from startIdx(inclusive) to endIdx (exclusive).
private static long getProduct(String input, int startIdx, int endIdx){
    long product = 1;
    for(int i=startIdx;i<endIdx;i++){
        product = product*(input.charAt(i)-48);
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: You can also consider pseudocode if this may be harder to understand for the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the review, but the code of @MartinR, is faster.

Comment: Are you sure? Could you combine my optimisation in Swift code along with Martin's and check. I am sure this should be faster because Martin or yours has complexity of O(13*n) where n is the length of input. Mine's worst/avg/best case is O(13*n) when all input is 0 and best case is O(n)

Comment: My bad. It is faster now. 0.012s. Thanks!

Comment: You can use just my answer without the changes from Martin's . It would work with same latency.

Comment: @thepace this algorithm can be further improved upon to guaranteed `O(n)` without ever having to call `getProduct` within the loop - see my answer.

Comment: The revised algorithm is actually _more_ efficient when it finds a zero, whereas this becomes _less_ efficient.

Comment: @thepace sorry this is a stupid question but what is the purpose of subtracting 48 after the `charAt(i)`

Comment: @YeLinAung to convert ASCII '0' .. '9' into the values 0 .. 9 (since ASCII '0' == 48)

Comment: charAt(i) = '1' = 49(ASCII). So to get the actual value subtract 48 which is '0'.
SO '0' - 48 = 0 (ASCII/CHAR to INT)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with a performance improvement: Your method repeatedly extracts substrings from the given digit string (which is a costly operation with Swift
strings), and then repeatedly converts the characters in a substring to an integer.
It is better to convert the entire string to an array of integers once with
a single string traversal:

```
func largestProduct(numDigits : Int) -> Int {

    let str = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
    let digits = Array(str).map { String($0).toInt()! }

    var maxNumber = 0
    let maxLength = digits.count - numDigits
    for var i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i {

        var number = 1
        for var j = i; j < i + numDigits; j++ {
            number *= digits[j]
        }

        if number > maxNumber {
            maxNumber = number
        }
    }

    return maxNumber
}
```

On my computer (with the program compiled in Release mode), this reduced the
time to compute `largestProduct(13)` from 0.065 seconds to 0.002 seconds.

(The rest of this review is about the code organisation and might be opinion based.)

I would pass the given digits as an argument to the `largestProduct()` function.
One advantage is that it is easier to add test cases.

```
for var i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i {  }
```

can be written more swifty using a *range*:

```
for i in 0 ..< maxLength { }
```

and the multiplication of the digits to a number can be done with `reduce()`.

Then your function would look like this:

```
func largestProduct(digits : [Int], numDigits : Int) -> Int {

    var maxNumber = 0
    let maxLength = digits.count - numDigits
    for i in 0 ..< maxLength {
        let number = reduce(i ..< i + numDigits, 1) { $0 * digits[$1] }
        if number > maxNumber {
            maxNumber = number
        }
    }

    return maxNumber
}
```

Your `printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode()` function is not optimal for reuse.
It is restricted to functions taking an Integer argument and returning
an integer, and the argument (`4` or `13` in this case) is part of the function.

I would change that to take a `()->Void` closure:

```
func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(operation:()->Void) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    println("Time elapsed : \(timeElapsed) s")
}
```

and define a function doing all the work:

```
func euler8()  {
    let str = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

    let digits = Array(str).map { String($0).toInt()! }

    let result = largestProduct(digits, 13)
    println(result)
}
```

Now you can measure the time with:

```
printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(euler8)
```

and the `printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode` function is fully reusable.

Comment: Thanks. Really clean. And it is more swifty like this. The performance went from 0.079 s to 0.035 s.

It is weird though that when I use the more swifty way of iteration, it is a little slower.
If I use `var i = 0; i <...;i++`, and make a loop instead of the reduce and map, it goes down to 0.029

Comment: @Mehdi.Sqalli: Did you compare in "Debug" or "Release" mode?

Comment: Release, every time.

Comment: @Mehdi.Sqalli please see my answer - I have an `O(n)` algorithm that should be substantially faster than this one.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same refactoring as @MartinR, this is my answer that performs 4x faster than the naive algorithm with a loop, and 6x faster than using `reduce`:

```
func largestProduct(digits: [Int], numDigits: Int) -> Int {

    var maxNumber = 0
    let maxLength = digits.count

    var runningCount = 0
    var number = 1

    for var i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i {
        var n = digits[i];
        if (n > 0) {
            number *= n
            if ++runningCount == numDigits {
                if number > maxNumber {
                    maxNumber = number
                }
                number /= digits[i - numDigits + 1]
                --runningCount
            }
        } else {
            runningCount = 0
            number = 1
        }
    }

    return maxNumber
}
```

It works by successively accumulating the product until the required number of digits is found, and then dividing by the first digit in preparation for the next iteration.

In this way it avoids performing `m` multiplications per digits, making the algorithm `O(n)` instead of `O(n * m)`, where `n` is the original string length and `m` is the number of digits to consider.

Furthermore, if the found digit is zero it knows to short circuit the evaluation and start again from the digit following the zero.

Comment: Yes, it is the same algorithm that @thepace used.
I updated my code with the new version. My code runs as fast as yours in Release mode. And I prefer the more swifty look of mine.

Comment: @Mehdi.Sqalli this is an improved version of thepace's algorithm and in my own benchmarks (which separated out the creation of the digit array from the search) this part far outperformed any other version here, doing 10k iterations in 5ms _total_.

Comment: You can check my code here : https://github.com/MehdiSv/Swift-Euler-Project/blob/master/LargestProductInSeries/LargestProductInSeries/main.swift

I have the same execution time.